# Highlight typos in the jupyter notebook markdown

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

When I write something in the jupyter notebook markdown field, the typos are not highlighted and often I ended up with something like this:

[image]

In almost all IDEs I have used so far, the typos are highlighted with a curly underline which was very convenient for me. Something like this:

[image]

Up till now I have not found anything that allows me to see this type of highlights. Does it exist?

Answer (score 72):

The popular Jupyter Notebook bundle [extension from Jupyter-contrib](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) contains a [spell checker](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/spellchecker). You can install and enable this (with admin privileges) like so:

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
jupyter nbextension enable spellchecker/main
```

This may be the most popular spell checker for Jupyter Notebooks, but note that it simply highlights words not in its dictionary, and does not offer corrections.

If the extension installed properly, you will see this message in the command line:

[image]

Now, in the browser, after opening Jupyter, you will see the button labelled "abc" beside the keyboard button, which you can toggle to enable/disable spell check:

[image]

The jupyter-contrib library has many other useful modules such as [code folding](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/codefolding) and [table of contents](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/toc2).

Comment: Here is how to install `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` using conda: `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

Comment: Note that you need to run the anaconda prompt "as administrator" to install this or other extensions.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following in a terminal:

```
ipython install-nbextension https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/downloads/calico-spell-check-1.0.zip
ipython install-nbextension https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/downloads/calico-document-tools-1.0.zip
ipython install-nbextension https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/downloads/calico-cell-tools-1.0.zip
jupyter nbextension enable calico-spell-check
```

You can see typos like
[image]
Find out [more](http://www.simulkade.com/posts/2015-04-07-spell-checking-in-jupyter-notebooks.html)

Afterwards, you need to activate the spell check in the Jupyter Notebook:

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.config.update({
  "load_extensions": {"calico-spell-check":true,
                      "calico-document-tools":true,
                      "calico-cell-tools":true
                     }
})
```

Comment: After installing it and invoking your command in the terminal I get: `Enabling notebook extension calico-spell-check...
      - Validating: OK` but nothing else. When I run jupyter notebook after that my markdown cells are not highlighted

Comment: @SalvadorDali do you see any errors in console output ?

Comment: any other answer friend , facing the same issue as @SalvadorDali

Answer (score 4):

The spellchecker and some other extensions from [jupyter_contrib_nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) is incompatible with the ipython `version 5.8.0.` and later. (Found that it works in some cases for the `version 5.0.0` [refer issue page of the same]. I'm not aware of its compatibility for the ipython versions between `5.0.0.` to `5.8.0.`, please do comment if anyone knows).
The calico's nbextension 'spellchecker' available at https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/downloads/calico-spell-check-1.0.zip is an outdated version [dated 2015]. But calico had updated their nbextensions and made avaliable at the github [repository](https://github.com/Calysto/notebook-extensions) [latest dated 2018]. It works fine for the ipython `version 5.8.0`.

**Installation**

```
git clone https://github.com/Calysto/notebook-extensions.git
cd notebook-extensions

jupyter nbextension install calysto --user

jupyter nbextension enable calysto/spell-check/main
```

Check its status:

```
jupyter nbextension list
```

When you now open or reload a notebook, there would be a new button visible with a check mark icon next to the button to open the command palette. You may click on it to check the spelling mistakes in the markdown cell.