# proofreading markdown cells in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, markdown

I would like to know if there is a way to proofread a text written in markdown cells in a Jupyter notebook?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "proofread"? Are you talking about [spell checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spell_checker)?

Comment: Yes exactly, I mean spell checking

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324039/highlight-typos-in-the-jupyter-notebook-markdown

Comment: I tried that but it did not work out, is there any other way to do it? or probably revising the original answer?