# Jupyter notebook spell checker with suggestions

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am running jupyter via anaconda in a web browser on windows. In nbextensions: I have tried,

1. calico-spell-check,
2. calico-spell-check,
3. spellchecker/main.

All highlight misspelled words fine but none suggest correct words.

Am I missing a set up step, my google fu is letting me down. Is there another extension that works as expected. I find it hard to believe that there is no true spell checker / corrector extension for a system designed around presenting of data, I must be missing a set up step or fundamental understanding of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48710561/8508004) you just get highlighting in the classic Jupyter notebook interface. The limitations of what can be done with that interface is one of the reasons the current path forward for Jupyter development is JupyterLab and [efforts based on similar underlying modern machinery](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6307), i.e., notebook version 7 is intended to look like the classic notebook interface while being based on the more modern components.

JupyterLab has spell check with suggestions available already added **for editing markdown cells** and **editing markdown documents**, see [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/spellchecker/pull/22). You can try it out in your browser now by going [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/spellchecker#jupyterlab-spellchecker) and clicking `launch binder` to bring up a session where the extension is already installed and working.

For code, JupyterLab already has a nice autocomplete implementation that you'll get when you start typing a word and press tab to see suggestions. Additionally, some ideas have been offered for extending the current spell checking extension for JupyterLab to handle code cells, see [tracking for this issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/spellchecker/issues/39).